# SSE with React and Express on the same machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, proxy

So, i have a web app with an ExpressJS backend and a React frontend. I am trying to use SSE to send messages from the server to the client.

```
router.get('/testSSE', async function(request, response)
{
    
    //const sessionID = sessionError(request.body.sessionID);
    response.writeHead(200, {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      });
      let counter = 0;
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const chunk = JSON.stringify({chunk: counter++});
        response.write(`data: ${chunk}\n\n`);
      }, 100);
    
      response.on("close", () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        response.end();
      });

});
```

If I connect to this using cURL or Postman, everything works and the messages keep coming.

On the React side, I have this code:

```
 componentDidMount() {
        const evtSource = new EventSource("/api/testSSE", {
          withCredentials: false,
        });
      
        evtSource.onopen = () => {
          console.log("SSE connection opened");
        };
      
        evtSource.onmessage = (event) => {
          console.log("Received SSE message:", event);
        };
      
        evtSource.onerror = (error) => {
          console.error("SSE error:", error);
        };
      }
```

which works if I use the full http://localhost:3000/api/testSSE URL, but that's not useful for a web app as it will only work when viewing the page on the machine hosting Express.

So, in my package.json for React, I have this line:
`"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"`
that works for every fetch to Express endpoints except this one.

What happens when I try to use the proxy URL is that the React client doesn't receive any message until I close the Express server, and then all the messages come at once.
So for whatever reason, the proxy is working but holding all the messages until I close the server.